# .htaccess mod_rewrite image/css/js URLs to template folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to rewrite all static components of a website (JS, images, CSS) from a "virtual" folder to a folder that's a tad deeper in the filesystem.

Example: `http://example.com/static/image.png` resolves to `http://example.com/application/templates/some_template/static/image.png`. Sorry for being a noob.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: “Sorry for being a noob.” – There is absolutely *NO* excuse for that! ;)

Comment: Well, that's probably why I'm coming to Stackoverflow to get answers to my questions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything that begins with `/static/` should be rewritten, you can use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^static/.+ /application/templates/some_template/$0
```